# Error while deserializing JSON using Jackson : Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize the json into MyClass object but every time I get the exception though I am able to serialize the JSON object.

```
**com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token**
```

The json I am trying to deserialize is

```
 {
  "siteName": "avisports",
  "csAssetTypes": [
    "Content_C",
    [
      "name",
      "description",
      "subheadline",
      "abstract",
      "body",
      "headline",
      "subheadline",
      "avi_content_title",
      "avi_content_body",
      "avi_content_headline",
      "avi_content_abstract"
    ]
  ]
}
```

my Bean is something like

```
public class GlContentServerConfig{

    private String siteName;
    private Map<String, List<String>> csAssetTypes = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    //getters ans setters
}
```

and my service method is

```
@Override
    public GlContentServerConfig getConfiguredAttributes(String siteName, String assetType) throws Exception {
        if (this.configMap == null) {
            this.configMap = this.configDAO.getAllConfigs();
        }

        GlContentServerConfig config = new GlContentServerConfig();
        config.setSiteName(siteName);               

        config.setCsAssetTypes(csService.getAssetTypeAttributeList(assetType));

        GloballinkConfig obj = this.configMap.get(siteName);
        if (obj != null) {
            String jsonValue = obj.getGlConfigValue();

            config=this.mapper.readValue(jsonValue, GlContentServerConfig.class); // error comes from this line
            //List<GlContentServerConfig> glconfigList= this.mapper.readValue(jsonValue, new TypeReference<GlContentServerConfig>(){});
            //List<GlContentServerConfig> glconfigList = this.mapper.readValue(jsonValue, this.mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, GlContentServerConfig.class));

            System.out.println("final : "+glconfigList.toString());

        }

        return config;
    }
```

I have tried all most all of the permutations and combinations. Few of them are commented in the code.
I am unable to figure out the way to use Jackson. please help me out.

Comment: But your `POJO` does not fit to your `JSON`. You have to create two new properties: `String csAssetTypes` and `List<String> csAttributes` and delete `Map<String, List<String>> csAssetTypes` property from your class.

Comment: JSON is wrong in this case . 
But the bean needs to be like that. I want a key value pair for iterations. So Map i have to use.

Answer (score 0):

add `@JsonProperty("csAssetTypes")` to your Bean :

```
public class GlContentServerConfig{

    private String siteName;
@JsonProperty("csAssetTypes") 
    private Map<String, List<String>> csAssetTypes = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    //getters ans setters
}
```